# After running adb kill-server I must reconnect usb device

Tags: android, usb, adb

```
System info:
Mac OS X 10.8.2 (issue occurs across 10.7 and 10.8 as well)
adb version 10.0.31
platform-tools version 17
```

Device:
Issue occurs in some manner on all devices tried, including various HTC and Samsung devices.

I'm getting odd behavior with adb: if I run

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

The device list is often empty or lists the device as "offline" until I manually unplug and re-plug the USB cable from my device.  Basically I must do this every time after running kill/start server.

This started happening with my last android sdk update and this wasn't a problem previously with adb, is anyone else running into this?  I've tried various workarounds and none of them work consistently across multiple devices and mac os versions.

Comment: I had this problem, but only on one device.  I put a USB extension cable in, and I unplug in at the connection to the extension cable, because I was messing up both my PC and Android USB ports when unplugging at either of those.

Answer (score 0):

instead of start-server after kill-server

execute this :: adb usb -- this restarts the adb in usb mode 
so the sequence of steps is

adb kill-server

adb usb

This will do the work for you , I don't know the exact reason why this is happening , maybe it refreshes its connections when you restart in usb mode which I know it should be doing when we start the server after killing it , its a minor bug anyways